# Associating a USER DEFINED language with a filetype in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So I know there have been questions regarding association with filetypes, but I can't find any about custom syntax highlighting. I have a user-defined language I use for TF2 scripting. It shows up in the drop down under "Define your Language" but not in the list in the style configurator window.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: if you're going to downvote, would you mind at least showing me to where this has already been asked?

Comment: Good question (and answer). For others who may run into this issue and may be misguided, Notepad++ has a "feature" where it requires you to re-open any opened files after a new user-defined language is associated, even if you restart Notepad++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Navigate back to `Language->Define your language...`
and select your custom style - a new TextBox `Ext.:` will appear to the right:
[image: Custom style selected]

You might have missed this, because `User Define Language` is selected by default - so the TextBox is hidden initially:

[image: Default selection]

Comment: This answer was not easy to find. I had imported G-CODE coloring so it was custom. 1+, thanks!

Comment: You can add multiple extensions by separating them by space "ext1 ext2 ext3"